# weird behavior while using ternary operator in for loop in python 3.5

Tags: python, python-3.x, ternary-operator

While I was testing ternary operator in python 3, I came across this weird phenomenon

```
import string
test = ""
testing = chr(0) if chr(0) in test else ""
for c in string.ascii_letters + testing:
    print(c)
```

would print a~Z 1 character per line, but

```
import string

test = ""
for c in string.ascii_letters + chr(0) if chr(0) in test else "":
    print(c)
```

would print nothing.
Can somebody give me an explanation?

Comment: Change to `for c in string.ascii_letters + (chr(0) if chr(0) in test else "")` and it will work.

Comment: Are there cases or platforms where a Python string contains a NUL character?

Comment: Check operator precedence: https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#operator-precedence

Comment: operator precedence. When you have a doubt, use parentheses.

Comment: why is the variable `test` or the `if` statement being used? as just doing this `for c in string.ascii_letters: print(c)` gives the same functionality

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is due to operator precedence: `+` binds tighter than `if`.

In the first snippet, `testing` evalutes to "" because `chr(0)` is not in `test`. So, the loop is over ascii_letters + "", ie just the letters.

In the second, the `+` is evaluated first; the `if` therefore evaluates the whole thing to `""` and the loop is just over the empty string.

Answer (score 0):

Change to:

```
for c in string.ascii_letters + (chr(0) if chr(0) in test else ""):
```

and it will work.

Why? [Operator precedence](https://docs.python.org/3.7/reference/expressions.html#operator-precedence). Your current code is actually:

```
for c in (string.ascii_letters + chr(0)) if chr(0) in test else "":
```